# Representing JSON in Java in a type-safe way

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is there a good way to represent JSON in Java in a convenient, easy-to-use, type-safe way?

We've been doing it using Maps, Lists, and primitives. This works fine, except that we have to add a lot of checks for missing values.

Jackson has a good way of handling the problem:

```
JsonNode node;
// returns MissingNode if name not present, no null check required
node.path("name").asText();
```

Jackson's syntax is uncomfortable in other ways, though. Their classes don't implement the Map or List interfaces, and the JsonNode interface isn't modifiable.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why not have POJOs and use Jackson to map from/to json only when needed?

Comment: There are JSON kits that have "getObject", "getArray", and "getXxxType" methods on arrays and objects, so that you never have to cast.  But that's not really doing much for you.  And the Jackson "asText" (or whatever) method is just a concealed cast.

Comment: @frant.hartm has a great suggestion. The use of POJOs with JsonCreator and JsonProperty annotations makes for very clean readable code. For your comment about always having to check for missing values, you should consider using JSR303 for validation.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure you are aware of it: Jackson can bind JSON to/from `Map`s just fine:

```
Map<String,Object> map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonSource, Map.class);
```

as well as full POJOs, like others commented:

```
POJO pojo = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonSource, POJO.class);
```

so that while you can certainly use `JsonNode` (aka Tree Model), there are alternative approaches that are often more convenient.